# How do you determine the Pull Direction for a GROMACS umbrella sampling simulation to generate the most accurate free energy value?

Tags: computational-physics, molecular-dynamics, non-equilibrium

I am trying to calculate the free energy between a protein and aptamer using GROMACS. Literature has indicated that one of the best way to do so is by performing an umbrella sampling MD simulation that involves a non-equilibrium pulling simulation that pulls the protein and aptamer apart. I have been running these simulations on certain protein-aptamer complexes but some of the free energy values that I am getting do not match the experimental free energy values from biology experiments. I am thinking that perhaps the pulling direction that I chose was not the best pulling direction. How do I determine the best/correct pulling direction?

Furthermore, what are the common sources of error when performing these umbrella sampling simulations? How do I make my simulations more accurate?

I am essentially using the procedure in [this tutorial](http://www.mdtutorials.com/gmx/umbrella/index.html) by Justin A. Lemkul, Ph.D., Virginia Tech Department of Biochemistry, except I am performing it on a protein-aptamer complex.